# PostgreSQL: Displaying inheritance relationship?

Tags: postgresql

I want to know if a certain PostgreSQL table is a part of any inheritance relationship (i.e. is a parent or a child of other table(s)).

Is there a query for that? Where is the inheritance data stored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT relname 
FROM pg_class c,pg_inherits i 
WHERE c.oid=i.inhrelid;
```

I am the guy that asked Adam about this, I found a solution so I added it here for future reference of others.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the pg_inherits system catalog:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/catalog-pg-inherits.html